# Magento 1 Enterprise to Magento 2 Open Source Migration

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool

We are looking my **migrate** a site from **Magento 1 Enterprise to Magento 2** Open Source. I am aware of how complicated a process this is and was just wondering if anyone knows of any tools to do this. Has anyone used **Cart2Cart** for this migration(if so how was their service?).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use other service for Data Migration Process. Magento Provides Data Migration Tool in that you can migrate your Magento 1 store into Magento 2.

Read and understand how Data Migration Process will work.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool.html
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

You can Migrate your Magento 1 Enterprise store into Magento 2 Open Source Edition.